# What are all of the negative integral solutions of $y^2+6xy-8x=0$?

Tags: quadratics

I got the answer as $(0,0)$ by making $D\ge 0$ (quadratic in $y$).
However, how do I know this is the only possible answer?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions with $x=-1$ though then $y$ would be positive

Comment: What do you mean by "negative integral"?  If you mean $x$ and $y$ are both negative integers, then $(x,y)=(0,0)$ would not work since $0$ is not negative.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $x$

$$
y = \frac{-6x \pm \sqrt{36x^2+32x}}{2}\\
= -3 x \pm \sqrt{9x^2+8x}
$$

If $x$ is negative, then to make $y$ negative as well we would need to choose the - branch and have

$$
9x^2+8x > 9x^2
$$

but that doesn't happen in this case. So no integral negative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$y^2+6xy-8x=0$ iff $y^2=2x(4-3y)$. Therefore, $\dfrac{y^2}{4-3y}=2x$ is an integer.

Computing the gcd of $y^2$ and $4-3y$ gives
$$
\frac{16}{4-3y} = 9 \frac{y^2}{4-3y} + (3y+4) = 18x + (3y+4)
$$
Therefore, $4-3y$ divides $16$ and so $4-3y \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8,\pm 1 6 \}$. The only integer solutions $y$ for which $x$ is also an integer are:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrr}
y & 2 & 0 & 4
\\
x & -1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
$$